# Bind JSON to HTML-elements not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind JSON to a list-element in HTML using knockoutJS. I'm using jQuery to get the JSON and then putting it into an observable array.
Logging the JSON in the console is working fine. It's working fine if I put everything in an array within the JavaScript but it's not pushing anything into the HTML with JSON. I do not get any errors in the console either.

My HTML looks like following

```
<div class="list">
    <ul id="listItems" data-bind="foreach: listItems">
        <li data-bind="text: number"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JavaScript

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false,
    });

    function getlistItems() {
        var self = this;
        self.listItems = ko.observableArray([]);
            $.getJSON("json_old.json", function(oldJSONData) {
                console.log(oldJSONData);
                self.listItems(oldJSONData);
            })
        }
    ko.applyBindings(new getlistItems());
```

And my JSON

```
{ "listItem": [
{ "letter": "a", "number": "1" },
{ "letter": "b", "number": "2" },
{ "letter": "c", "number": "3" },
{ "letter": "d", "number": "4" },
{ "letter": "e", "number": "5" },
{ "letter": "f", "number": "6" },
{ "letter": "g", "number": "7" },
{ "letter": "h", "number": "8" },
{ "letter": "i", "number": "9" } ]}
```

What am I missing? I want to push the number-property of the JSON into the list.

Comment: In your JSON you have a property called `listItem` that is an array of objects.  You need to pass this property:   `self.listItems(oldJSONData.listItem)`

Comment: You! I love you! How could I miss that? Thank you!